# How do I order a view using a column that is not in the view itself?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on my sql assignment and there is this question about sorting a view using a column that is outside the view. So I had the idea of joining the view with the column itself, without showing the column the in the query, and this is what I found online

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM vwCustomerOrder
INNER JOIN ORDERDETAILS.ORDERLINENUMBER
ON vwCustomerOrder.QUANTITYORDERED = ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITYORDERED
ORDER BY ORDERDETAILS.ORDERLINENUMBER)
```

This shows a ORA-00942 error, which said that the view is not reaching the column, anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: In the fourth line remove `.ORDERLINENUMBER`. And... you don't need to enclose the query into an external one; just use the internal query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the missing column is coming from the same table , then select from origin table instead of view , the join would be redundant .
if not if the relationship is one-one then join can work :

```
SELECT *
FROM vwCustomerOrder
INNER JOIN ORDERDETAILS
ON vwCustomerOrder.QUANTITYORDERED = ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITYORDERED
ORDER BY ORDERDETAILS.ORDERLINENUMBER
```

Comment: Why don't you accept/upvote the answer, then, @Redgehog?